# Difference between www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/homepage

Tags: cms, index

I have a CMS page used for the homepage on the site with the identifier 'homepage'.

I have also called some extra blocks inside local.xml inside the `<cms_index_index>` tag in local.xml, see below (for example the `home.featured.products` block called at the bottom of the page) :

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">

    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
    <!--remove the default CMS page heading and content blocks so they don't appear at the top of the page-->
    <remove name="page_content_heading" />
    <remove name="cms.wrapper" />

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery/column-height-init.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>

    <!--create homepage structure - homepage.blocks holds all the other blocks so we can control the layout better-->
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="homepage.blocks" template="cms/homepage/homepage-blocks.phtml">
            <block type="qbanner/qbanner" name="qbanner.home" template="qaz/qbanner/qbanner.content.top.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="home.collection.links" template="cms/homepage/collection-links.phtml" />
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="latest.news.home" template="cms/homepage/latest-news-home.phtml" />-->
            <block type="core/template" name="rss.feed" template="cms/homepage/rss-feed.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="featured.products" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="latest.blog.home" template="cms/homepage/latest-blog-home.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="twitter.feed" template="cms/homepage/twitter-feed.phtml" />
            <!--call the heading and content for the home again here (different template files from normal CMS pages now)-->
            <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading.home" template="cms/homepage/content_heading.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper.home" translate="label">
                <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
                <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

My problem is that this is working fine if I go to `http://www.mysite.com/`, but if I go to `http://www.mysite.com/homepage` then the XML above is not being applied, I guess because `http://www.mysite.com/homepage` is not treated as the CMS index?

I have set the Home page in System...Config...Web..Default Pages as this page.

Is there any way I can overcome this? I have a complaint from a client that the "Preview" link in the Magento admin panel under CMS...Pages is not showing the homepage correctly (because the Preview link is going to `http://www.mysite.com/homepage`)

I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about putting a line into your .htaccess to rewrite the `/homepage` URL to the `/` one? This would not only solve your problem but would be good for SEO, since you wouldn't have duplicate content.

e.g.
`Redirect 301 /homepage /`

Answer (score 3):

just copy (cut) your xml content and paste it in the desing -> Layout Update XML of your page

Eg: CMS->Page

edit your page and navigate to `Design` on left, in the `Layout Update XML` paste your xml content here

Comment: Doing this means that when viewing http://www.mysite.com/ all the blocks are called on the page twice, once by local.xml and once by the Custom Design.

Comment: You can eliminate the local.xml content once this is done.